# Hammer.js: Is there a way to add a custom touch recognizer without using the hammer manager?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, touch-event

I am presently using the hammer.js touch library to do tap and pan events.  I have come to a point where I now need a double tap event.

According to the double tap example, the hammer manager creates a new hammer object without the preset recognizers.  You basically add/build your own.

```
//We create a manager object, which is the same as Hammer(), but without the presetted recognizers. 
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
```

To add custom recognizers you call a .add and give the parameters for the recognizer being added.

```
// Tap recognizer with minimal 2 taps
mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }) );
```

I have been able to add a custom recognizer with the manager, but lose the functioning of my previously working default tap and drag events.  Is there a way to add a Hammer recognizer without the use of the hammer manager?  And if not, then is there a way to use the manager and still keep the default preset recognizers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, then the solution is to add your custom recognizer to the default Hammer manager.

```
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }));
```

When you do `new Hammer(element)` this just creates a `Hammer.Manager` instance with the default recognizers added to it.